# I don't receive an action on my BroadcastReceiver - AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

It's my first time working with Bluetooth module in Android, I'm trying to scan devices not paired yet and show them in a message but it doesn't work. I have tried a lot of things but nothing. I have all the permissions needed. This is part of my code

```
mScanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                //registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);

                if(mBlueAdapter!=null && mBlueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    listAdapter.clear();
                    mBlueAdapter.startDiscovery();
                    showToast("Discovery");
                    IntentFilter filtera = new IntentFilter();
                    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
                    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

                    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);

                }
```

And this is my BroadcastReceiver

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                listAdapter.add(device.getName() + device.getAddress());
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                showToast("Action Scan Mode " );

            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                mpossibleBtn.setText("Scanning Bluetooth Devices");
                showToast("Scannning Bluetooth Devices... " );
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
                mpossibleBtn.setText("Scanning in progress...");
                showToast("Scanning in progress... " );
            }


            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)) {
                showToast("Action Scan Mode " );
                int modeValue=intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                if(modeValue==BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE){
                    mPairedTv.setText("The device is not in discoverable mode but still can receive connections");
                } else if(modeValue==BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE){
                    mPairedTv.setText("The device is in discoverable mode");
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    String deviceName = device.getName();
                    String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
                    showToast("onReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());
                } else if (modeValue==BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE){
                    mPairedTv.setText("The device is not in discoverable mode and can't receive connection");
                } else{
                    mPairedTv.setText("Error");
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I'm testing the app on my Xiaomi cellphone.

Comment: which permissions do you own? you probably need `BLUETOOTH`, `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` and on newer OS versions also `LOCATION` (not sure `FINE` or `COARSE` is sufficient)

Comment: I have                                                                                                                      
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Answer (score 0):

you need to ADD after registering receiver

```
mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

Comment: actions used in question should be send by system when it perform BT scan

Comment: I tried to put    if(mBlueAdapter.isDiscovering()) showToast("Started"); Rigth after startDiscovery and it doesn't work, i changed the permissions of location to fine and nothing

Answer (score 0):

Start discovery after registering your receiver.

```
IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intent);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);

mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

Or in your case

```
IntentFilter filtera = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

Also ensure you have bt permissions on your manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

On some phones you will need to restart the adapter first.

```
  mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
  mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
```

for some time on the broadcast receiver if you don't receive BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED after starting discovery,  you have to prompt device restart as the bt may not be working properly.you can use a timer to check this.

Comment: I tried but it's the same, nothing, I cheked my permissions and everithing good. I tried to scan btdevices with my systems phone (while my app is running in brackground) and i return tu my app and it receive an action. In this case ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.

Comment: I tried to put    if(mBlueAdapter.isDiscovering()) showToast("Started"); Rigth after startDiscovery and it doesn't work, i changed the permissions of location to fine and nothing

Comment: startDiscovery() is asynchronous so when you ask the isDiscovering() it might not have started yet

Comment: On some phones you will need to restart the adapter mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
mBluetoothAdapter.enable();

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just found my error. In this case BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions have a protection Level of normal, and so all you need to do is request them in the manifest. The location permissions are dangerous, though, and so on Android 6.0+ devices, with a targetSdkVersion of 23 or higher, you need to request those at runtime.

I alredy have the permissions however, we do need to request ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION at runtime.

This time the code works

```
mScanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(mBlueAdapter!=null && mBlueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
                filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

                registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);

                if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (mMap != null) {
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                         mBlueAdapter.startDiscovery();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Permission to access the location is missing. Show rationale and request permission
                    PermissionUtils.requestPermission(MainActivity.this, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
                      mBlueAdapter.startDiscovery();
                }

                }
```

});